# Reducir el tamaño de la carpeta Node_modules en React Admin

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estoy tratando de entender cómo hacer para que mi carpeta node_modules de mi proyecto react-admin no pese 350mb. Básicamente es una página básica con un tabla donde podes hacer acciones CRUD a través de formularios. Entiendo que deberia haber alguna forma de reducir la cantidad de dependencias que no uso. Pero no entiendo cómo. Si pongo en esa carpeta sólamente las dependencias listadas en mi archivo package.json, no compila el proyecto.
Mi archivo package.json contiene:

```
{

  "name": "react-admin",

  "version": "0.1.0",

  "private": true,

  "dependencies": {

    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",

    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",

    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.147",

    "@mui/material": "^5.14.12",

    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.16.0",

    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",

    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",

    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",

    "formik": "^2.4.5",

    "ra-data-json-server": "^4.13.3",

    "react": "^18.2.0",

    "react-admin": "^4.13.3",

    "react-crud-admin": "^1.0.48",

    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",

    "react-hooks": "^1.0.1",

    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",

    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"

  },
```

Comment: probaste eliminando dependencias con npm remove? de todas maneras si necesitas desplegar el proyecto las dependencias no usadas no se van a incluir...

Comment: No he hecho el deploy de react admin. Recien lo cree, y genera una carpeta con el build de 5mb. Con esa carpeta que me generó debería funcionar directamente? Disculpa.. soy nuevo en lo que es deploy. Y tengo que enviar el proyecto sin que sea extremadamente pesado..

Comment: Si, deberia funcionar, al hacer la build para desplegarlo 'minificas' tu proyecto, se eliminan los espacios en blanco entre las líneas de código y se quitan las dependencias no usadas, de hecho 5mb para un proyecto simple hasta me parece mucho, no tenes imagenes grandes o videos dentro?

Comment: No, pero agradezco que me ayudaras con lo del tamaño. Voy a probar como funciona el build.. Gracias